# Packaging an application into .app in MAC os

Tags: macos, installation, builder, bitrock

I have a application in MAC os with .app extension. It had certain dependent folders for e.g frontend and backend having resources needed for the application to run. All the dependencies and the .app were included in a folder. My task was to remove the folder and just have a .app in the applications folder i.e the final installation path should look like /Application/MyApp.app , where earlier this MyApp.app installed location was /Applications/My App/MyApp.app.

I moved all the dependencies inside the MyApp.app/Contents/Resources folder . Now i am using bitrock installer for MAC to generate a dmg . Is it necessary to first generate a pkg out of MyApp.app? The build is happening in bamboo server where the bambbobuild path is also My App/MyApp.app